# Duplicating an @idea, getting "No route matches" error [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am creating an app where a user can create and @idea and then another @user can 'fork' the @idea. To do this I used the duplicate method [ActiveRecord::Core#dup](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup).

This is what I want to happen. @user opens up the @idea show page and clicks on an icon that is supposed to lead him/her to a new @forked_idea edit page which will allows them to edit the original @idea and save it as a new @forked_idea.

Here is the snippet from my show page for the original @idea. When the icon is clicked, I would like it to route to the an edit page (in or to for the idea)

```
<%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-code-fork fa-5x'></i>".html_safe, idea_forked_idea_path(@idea), method: :get %>
```

When I click on the icon to fork an @idea, I am presented with this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"forked_ideas", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :idea_id=>#<Idea id: 78,
```

Here is the app/controllers/ideas_controller.rb

```
class ForkedIdeasController < ApplicationController

def edit
end

def update
  @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
  @forked_idea = @idea.dup
  if @forked_idea.save(forked_idea_attributes)
    redirect_to forked_ideas_edit_path(@idea), notice: "Forking this idea!"
  else
    render ideas_path
  end   
end


def destroy
  if @idea.destroy
    redirect_to ideas_path, notice: "idea has been deleted"
  else
    redirect_to ideas_path, notice: "idea has been deleted"
  end
end

private

def forked_idea_attributes
  params.require(:forked_idea).permit([:title, :body, :tag_list, :image])
end

end
```

end

My model for forked_idea:

```
class ForkedIdea < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
```

Routes

```
resources :ideas do
  resources :forked_ideas, only:[:edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

Here is the `rake routes`

```
edit_idea_forked_idea GET    /ideas/:idea_id/forked_ideas/:id/edit(.:format)    forked_ideas#edit
     idea_forked_idea PATCH  /ideas/:idea_id/forked_ideas/:id(.:format)         forked_ideas#update
                      PUT    /ideas/:idea_id/forked_ideas/:id(.:format)         forked_ideas#update
                      DELETE /ideas/:idea_id/forked_ideas/:id(.:format)         forked_ideas#destroy
                ideas GET    /ideas(.:format)                                   ideas#index
                      POST   /ideas(.:format)                                   ideas#create
             new_idea GET    /ideas/new(.:format)                               ideas#new
            edit_idea GET    /ideas/:id/edit(.:format)                          ideas#edit
                 idea GET    /ideas/:id(.:format)                               ideas#show
                      PATCH  /ideas/:id(.:format)                               ideas#update
                      PUT    /ideas/:id(.:format)                               ideas#update
                      DELETE /ideas/:id(.:format)                               ideas#destroy
```

Comment: can u run --> 'rake routes' command and show us the result

Comment: @Jack -- I have included the routes, Jack. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that "id" is nil - given your error message:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"forked_ideas", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :idea_id=>#<Idea id: 78,
```

And routes you don't seem to have a route for the case when "id" is nil.